# Installing Matplotlib on CentOS 6.5

Tags: python, matplotlib, freetype2, centos6.5

I'm trying to get matplotlib-1.4.0 installed on CentOS 6.5 with Python 2.7.8. I've tried installing with pip and from source. I initially got an error message stating I needed a newer version of Freetype2, which I then installed (version 2.5.3) to /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/include, and /usr/local/lib. The older version of Freetype2 (2.3.11) is in /usr/bin, /usr/include/freetype2/freetype, and /usr/lib.

Now when I try installing matplotlib (python setup.py build) it looks like the include paths are all pointing to the wrong (old) version of Freetype2, and I can't figure out how to change the appropriate paths to point to the newer version of Freetype2. The actual error message is below, and is pretty messy. I couldn't find much about his error online, but I can see that the wrong Freetype2 path so I'm guessing that's what causing the issue.  Any tips?

Found tips on other threads about adding /usr/include/freetype symlink to point to /usr/local/include/freetype2, but that didn't help.

```
building 'matplotlib.ft2font' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -m64 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mtune=generic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -I/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I. -Iextern -I/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/include/python2.7 -c src/ft2font.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/ft2font.o
In file included from /usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1761:0,
                 from /usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                 from src/file_compat.h:7,
                 from src/ft2font.cpp:7:
/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
In file included from src/ft2font.cpp:7:0:
src/file_compat.h:31:0: warning: "npy_fseek" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_common.h:86:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
src/file_compat.h:32:0: warning: "npy_ftell" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_common.h:91:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
src/ft2font.cpp: In member function ‘Py::Object FT2Image::py_write_bitmap(const Py::Tuple&)’:
src/ft2font.cpp:184:15: warning: unused variable ‘offset’ [-Wunused-variable]
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -m64 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mtune=generic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -I/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I. -Iextern -I/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/include/python2.7 -c src/mplutils.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/mplutils.o
In file included from /usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                 from src/mplutils.h:18,
                 from src/mplutils.cpp:6:
/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1182:0: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/include/features.h:162:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1204:0: warning: "_XOPEN_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/include/features.h:164:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -m64 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mtune=generic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -I/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I. -Iextern -I/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/include/python2.7 -c extern/CXX/cxxsupport.cxx -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extern/CXX/cxxsupport.o
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -m64 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mtune=generic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -I/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I. -Iextern -I/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/include/python2.7 -c extern/CXX/cxx_extensions.cxx -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extern/CXX/cxx_extensions.o
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -m64 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mtune=generic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -I/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I. -Iextern -I/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/include/python2.7 -c extern/CXX/IndirectPythonInterface.cxx -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extern/CXX/IndirectPythonInterface.o
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O3 -m64 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mtune=generic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DPYCXX_ISO_CPP_LIB=1 -I/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I. -Iextern -I/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/include/python2.7 -c extern/CXX/cxxextensions.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extern/CXX/cxxextensions.o
g++ -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/ft2font.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/mplutils.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extern/CXX/cxxsupport.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extern/CXX/cxx_extensions.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extern/CXX/IndirectPythonInterface.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extern/CXX/cxxextensions.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/lib -lfreetype -lstdc++ -lm -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/matplotlib/ft2font.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: I would remove that freetype sym link as it will probably break other things on your system.  Otherwise, your error appears to be with the python 2.7 install.  Can you try against 2.6?

Comment: I think I may have found a possible solution here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/Ev4iULHB3ms  It looks like including the --enable-shared option to the configure script when building Python may resolve this issue. It will be tough for me to re-build Python from scratch since it's on a cluster that multiple users may be using at any given time...I will update if I am ever able to attempt the re-install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally had time to return to this and it had nothing to do with Freetype. The issue was the wrong version of libpython2.7 being picked up during the build. Specifically in this line:

```
g++ -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/ft2font.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/mplutils.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extern/CXX/cxxsupport.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extern/CXX/cxx_extensions.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extern/CXX/IndirectPythonInterface.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/extern/CXX/cxxextensions.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/lib -lfreetype -lstdc++ -lm -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/matplotlib/ft2font.so
```

The first -L directory is /usr/local/lib which contained a different version of the python library (libpython2.7.a) than the one I should have been compiling against. I moved this file temporarily and the build was then successful (it found the correct version in /usr/local/python2/2.7.8/x86_64/gcc46/nonet/lib).

I'm not exactly sure where the python lib in /usr/local/lib originated from. If it's the system version then this could be considered a bug in the matplotlib build script.

Comment: I'm also running into this issue. Is there a way to set the prefix / python version in Matplotlib?

Comment: Not that I am aware.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm using python-2.6 I just bodged a way through the exact same freetype error: essentially you can simply download the matplotlib python archive and edit the requirement for freetype-2.4 to freetype-2.3.  This was all done in a virtualenv naturally.

1. get a copy of the current latest matplotlib

   pip install --download . matplotlib==1.4.0
2. untar the result
   tar -xzvf matplotlib-1.4.0.tar.gz
3. edit the explicit requirement for freetype from 2.4 to 2.3 (line 945)

   vi matplotlib-1.4.0/setupext.py

   min_version='2.4', version=version)
4. recreate the archive

   tar -czvf matplotlib-1.4.0.tar.gz
5. install the requirements

   pip install numpy

   pip install geojson==1.0.6
6. Install your modified local archive, and watch as it compiles

   pip install --verbose matplotlib-1.4.0.tar.gz

Comment: I should add that this[1] is the justification for assuming that Freetype 2.3 should be fine:  1. https://github.com/mdboom/matplotlib/commit/96a3ea27cb0525704eacbe1b483a2479cdad19dc

Comment: It never even occurred to me to try this. Does it pass all (or a majority of) the tests? Seems curious that the developers would enforce 2.4 if it wasn't needed. Thanks for spending time on this, I'll give it a try sometime over the next few days and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I only ran these, and there was a set of 13 failures.  Not quite sure what they were:               
(matplotlibcopy)$ python ./tests.py -sv --processes=5 --process-timeout=300
Ran 4663 tests in 425.891s

FAILED (KNOWNFAIL=378, SKIP=8, errors=2, failures=13)

Comment: Finally had a chance to try this and unfortunately it did not resolve the problem.

Comment: @commanderdata That's dissapointing.  Is /usr/local/lib/python.2.7.a valid? What happens if you pass in the PIC flag as the linker message suggests?

Comment: see my comment under the OP. I'll try this at some point and report back. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this hint solved my situation, and I hope that version 2.3 will not give me problems. To the record, I haven't installed matplotlib via pip, but by `python setup.py build
python setup.py install` as explained in the [INSTALL file](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/INSTALL#L127)

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem when compiling the matplotlib-1.4.3 from source code. After this error, I simply `export LDFLAGS="/home/ubuntu/softwares/python-2.7.11/lib"`, then `python setup.py install`. The error is gone and I can install the matplotlib successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to install the most recent version of `matplotlib` compatible with **Python 2.6** on **CentOS 6** (currently 6.9 when I wrote this), here's how I did.

Logged as `root`, type:

```
sudo yum install -y epel-release
sudo yum install -y python-pip
sudo yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ python-argparse python-devel freetype-devel libpng-devel
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install numpy==1.11.3  # latest version working with Python 2.6
pip install --upgrade distribute  # required by matplotlib 1.4
pip install -I setuptools  # "distribute" installation will remove setuptools, so we need to reinstall it
pip install matplotlib==1.4.3  # latest version working with Python 2.6
```